# Arrays dinamicos en C

Tags: c

se me pide que amplie un array de n elementos en uno, y tras sumarlo , el resultado 
de esta operacion se inserta en el elemento v[n+1], el problema es que el resultado de la suma es "basura", no el resultado real, paso el codigo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/*
* Realiza un programa en C que defina un vector dinámico de n elementos
* enteros siendo n un valor introducido por el usuario, suponiendo que
* el vector esta inicializado, escribe también una función que recita
* dicho vector  y el tamaño n y añada un elemento mas que sea la suma
* de los elementos del vector. Finalmente la función deberá volcar todo
* el contenido del vector en un fichero binario.
* Reservados 
*/


int muestravector(int* v,int num);
int sumaelementos(int* v, int num);
int main() {
int n, * v1, i;
printf("Introduzca cuantos elementos tiene el vector\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
v1 = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
printf("Ahora por favor introduzca los elementos (solo numeros enteros)\n");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%i", &v1[i]);
}
muestravector(v1, n);
sumavector(v1, n);

return 0;}

//Cabecera ==> int muestravector(int* v)
//Precondicion ==> Recibe un vector incializado
//Postcondicion ==> Muestra n elementos del vector  
int muestravector(int* v, int num) {
  printf("A continuacion se muestran los elementos del vector\n");
  for (int j = 0; j < num; j++)
{
    printf("%i\n", v[j]);
}
 }

 //Cabecera ==> int sumavector(int* v)
//Precondicion ==> Recibe un vector incializado
//Postcondicion ==> suma n elementos del vector  
int sumavector(int* v, int num) {
int x;
num = num + 1;
v = (int*)realloc(v,num);

for ( x = 0; x < num; x++)
{
    v[num]= v[num] + v[x];
}

printf("\n La suma de todos los elementos es: %i", v[num]);
}
```

---

Era otra cosa, al vector tener N-1 elementos y no n elementos, el v[num] me imprimis un número de mas y no realizaba nada, mañana subiré el resto corregido, muchísimas gracias

Comment: Declaras la variable `sumaelementos` pero esta función resulta que realmente se llama `sumavector` ¿En qué quedamos? El código que has puesto **no compila**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema viene desde que `v[num]` no tiene ningún valor asignado, entonces cuando realizas la iteración, estas iterando sobre ningún valor o mejor dicho un valor inesperado(basura). Podrías agregar el valor a `v[num] = 0`, entonces quedaría.

```
    v[num] = 0;
   for ( x = 0; x < num; x++){
     v[num]= v[num] + v[x];
   }
```